# Styling BorderPane top with CSS

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder, builder, scene

Is it possible to style BorderPane top with CSS? For example I want to color it with different colors for left, right, center, bottom and top. Is that possible?

Comment: Style the components they are in those regions

Comment: @James_D would you know the class name BorderPane top for example? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: There isn't one. Just set it yourself on the component you put into the top.

Comment: @James_D Thank you James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. All of them are just properties.

The `BorderPane` control gets nodes pointed by those properties and places these nodes on its surface directly, i.e. without any intermediate nodes.

For example, place one `Pane` into center and one `Button` into bottom of the `BorderPane`. Then you can see there is no any nodes in the hierarhy between the `BorderPane` and the `Pane` and between the `BorderPane` and the `Button`:

[image]

Comment: Thank you again. Man, you give the best answers! I hope there were more people like you around.

Comment: @Roger I think there are plenty of them on barbeque today (as my level with JavaFX is 3 weeks only :)

Comment: Good point haha. Nevertheless your knowledge is still gold and really appreciate the help :) Cheers!